# What is the average height above ground of the wings of a 777-200?

Tags: aircraft-design

I have read somewhere that this is 18.4 to 18.6 m but not sure of the source. Is this information is correct?

Comment: The [TAIL height](https://modernairliners.com/boeing-777/boeing-777-specs/?amp) (IE: how tall is the aircraft) is 18.5 m for the -200 and 18.6 m for the -300. That's nothing to do w/average WING height, which are not horizontal to the ground and bend upwards to tip so average is a meaningless #.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a single number for ground clearance. For the wing, Boeing publishes the height of the wing ***tip*** as between 16 ft 10 inches and 17 feet 4 inches. You can view all the other ground clearance numbers published by Boeing Aircraft for the purpose of airport planning [here](http://wpage.unina.it/fabrnico/DIDATTICA/PGV/Specifiche_Esercitazioni/B777/Manuale%20777_23.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much.